# Class I lever: force needed to rotate slab into socket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

I have a 5m-long cuboid slab weighing 1000kg, which I would like to lift (from one end) into a socket cut into the ground. The slab is already resting at 10 degrees from horizontal and the fulcrum (F1) is 1m from the end of the slab. See diagram:

[image: diagram]

A couple of questions:

1) What vertical force is needed to rotate the slab clockwise around the fulcrum?

2) What force, orthogonal to the angle of the slab (i.e 100 degrees from horizontal) would be required to rotate the slab clockwise around the fulcrum?

I understand that if the slab was resting at horizontal and the fulcrum was at the very opposite end to the end being lifted, then exactly half the slab's weight would need to be borne in order to raise it(?):

F = ma

F = 0.5 * 1000

F = 500

But I cannot be sure of how to account for a) different resting angles and b) differently positioned fulcrums, though I know the cosine of the resting angle is involved somehow.

Comment: Is the slab constrained to rotate around the fulcrum? i.e. is it pinned with a rod, or just resting on the surface?

Comment: pinned with a rod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a simple lever. You draw a free body diagram and add all the forces acting.

[image: FBD]

In red is $F_2$ the applied lifting force required. In blue $W= m g$ is the total weight of the slab and in brown $F_2$ the pivot reaction force. Also notable are the horizontal separation of these forces $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the center of gravity.

Now, write out the sum of forces and sum of torques and equal them to zero for balance.

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_1 + F_2 - W & = 0 \\
  x_1\, F_1 - x_2 \, F_2 & = 0
\end{aligned} $$

Solve this for $F_1$ and $F_2$

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_1 & = \left( \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2} \right) m g \\
  F_2 & = \left( \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \right) m g
\end{aligned} $$

So to lift the slab, you need

$$ F_2 > \left( \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \right) m g  $$

Using the angle from horizontal the moment arms are

$$ \begin{aligned}
  x_1 & = \left( \frac{\ell}{2} -c \right) \cos \theta \\
  x_2 & = \left( \frac{\ell}{2} \right) \cos(\theta) 
\end{aligned} $$

where $\ell=5$ is the slab length, and $c=1$ is the contact location from the end. This means the lifting force is

$$\boxed{ F_2 > \left( \frac{ \frac{\ell}{2}-c}{\ell-c} \right) m g } $$

Comment: do the above calculations take into the account the angle of rest (10 degrees) or is this not relevant when applying vertical lift? would less force be required if the lift was applied orthogonal to the resting angle?

Comment: ah...the centre of gravity would shift as the angle changes...

Comment: What is important are the distances $x_1$ and $x_2$ forming the lever. As the slab lifts, those values change. Also, note that if the slab gets in contact with the far wall of the socket, it changes the problem because now you have to deal with friction and the Painleve effect.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. My approach to solving $x_2$ would be:
sin(80°) = $x_2$ / 2.5 ->
0.98 = $x_2$ / 2.5  ->
$x_2$ = 0.98 · 2.5 ->
$x_2$ = 2.45

Comment: In the above example I am calculating:
 $x_1$ = sin(80)  · 4 = 3.9 |
 $x_2$ =sin(80)  · 2.5 = 2.45 |

Which gives :
 $F_2$ = ( 3.9 / 6.35 ) · *mg* |
 $F_2$ = 0.61 · *mg* |
which means more than half the weight has to be lifted which seems incorrect. Should $x_1$ describe the distance between the centre of gravity and  F1?

Comment: From the diagram I am expecting $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_2 \approx \frac{\ell}{2} \approx 2.5 $. The calc should be $x_1 = \left( \frac{\ell}{2}-c \right) \cos(\theta)$ and $x_2 = \left( \frac{\ell}{2} \right) \cos(\theta)$ where $\ell=5$, $c=1$ and $\theta = 10°$.  This yields $\boxed{F_2 = 0.444 m g}$.

Comment: I made a math error above. The results should be $\boxed{F_2 = 0.375 \,m g}$ the (inverse) mechanical advantage ratio being $$ \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} = \frac{ \frac{\ell}{2}-c}{\ell-c} = \frac{2.5-1}{5-1}= 0.375$$

Comment: shouldn't $x_2$ = l/2 * cos(θ) ?

Comment: It is. I wrote $x_2 = \left( \frac{\ell}{2} \right) \cos(\theta)$ in my comment above.

Comment: Does this take into account the proportion of the slab's weight being borne by the pivot point? This would increase as the angle increased meaning less weight would have be lifted?

Comment: this would effectively be added to the above equation: mg = weight * cos(angle) Reference physicsforums.com/threads/lifting-one-end-of-a-beam.151526

Comment: Yes. The weight is shared between the pivot and the lifting. But the situation does not account for friction on the pivot.

Comment: Note, use a free body diagram and balance the forces and torques to solve for any specific situation.